# Typescript: Extract type from union of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a union of objects like so

```js
type NotificationState =
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "pending" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "deployingNodes" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "provisioningEndpoints" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "connecting" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "applyingCredentials" }
    | { kind: "static"; state: "online" }
    | { kind: "static"; state: "updating" }
    | { kind: "static"; state: "maintenance" }
    | { kind: "static"; state: "unknown" }
```

Does typescript support a way to create a new type via a filter? e.g., I want to create a type where `kind` is `dynamic`

```js
type DynamicNotificationState =
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "pending" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "deployingNodes" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "provisioningEndpoints" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "connecting" }
    | { kind: "dynamic"; state: "applyingCredentials" }
```

Comment: `Extract<NotificationState, {kind: 'dynamic'}>`

Comment: @kaya3 perfect! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
type DynamicNotificationState<T> =
    | { kind: T; state: "pending" }
    | { kind: T; state: "deployingNodes" }
    | { kind: T; state: "provisioningEndpoints" }
    | { kind: T; state: "connecting" }
    | { kind: T; state: "applyingCredentials" }

const v: DynamicNotificationState<'dynamic'> = {
    
}
```